# PIL Image.open display image reversely rotated

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, pytorch, mnist

I'm working on predicting the number picture as  below with MNIST dataset and [LeNet Model](https://www.kaggle.com/vincentman0403/pytorch-v0-3-1b-on-mnist-by-lenet/output) . Firstly, I show test images with `Image.open`, it displays test images in the way of reversely rotated.

[image]

```
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np

img = Image.open('./test/2.png').convert('L')
img = np.invert(img) # convert to white on black
pl.imshow(np.asarray(img), origin='lower', cmap=cm.Greys_r)
pl.show()
```

Another issue is  the accuracy ratio of prediction seem very low. For example, the `2` here has been predicted as `4`.

Someone could help with that or explain?  In my point of views, this number is much clear than handwriting MNIST. Thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: To get the image right side up, use `origin='upper'` perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`imshow` just sees an array of data. So specifying `origin='lower'` means you're telling `imshow` that the origin of your data is in the lower corner. However, image data has its origin in the upper corner so you can either remove `origin=` completely (the default is 'upper') or specify 'upper'.

```py
pl.imshow(np.asarray(img), cmap=cm.Greys_r)
```

or

```py
pl.imshow(np.asarray(img), origin='upper', cmap=cm.Greys_r)
```

Comment: Thanks. I have another question, do you know how to preprocess the example images to MNIST style in order to improve accuracy ratio of predictions.